# deleteMany showing 0 deleted but actually deleting the documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this controller is deleting all the todos of particular user but in response it is showing `{n: 0, deletedCount: 0, ok: 1}`, does anyone knows the solution of it?

```
exports.deleteAll = async (req, res) => {

    const { id } = req.user

    console.log('id', id);

    try {
        // const deleteAllTodos = await TodoModel.findByIdAndDelete(id)

        const deleteAllTodos = await TodoModel.deleteMany({ createdBy: id}, function (err) { 

        console.log('err', err) })

        res.send({ success: true, message: "All todos deleted successfully", deleteAllTodos })

    } catch (error) {

        console.log('Error:', error.message);

        res.status(500).json({
            message: "Internal server error",
            success: false,
            error: error.message
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Mongoose or just the NodeJS driver?

Comment: yes I am using mongoose as well

Comment: `{ n: 0, deletedCount: 0, ok: 1 }` - that shows the deleted count.

Comment: yes it's showing this, whereas it should be showing number of matched todos and deleted todos which are more than 1 but definitely not 0

Comment: You are mixing await and callback syntax - that might be the problem Remove the callback from the code and try. See this example: [Mongoose deleteMany()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-deleteMany).

Comment: removing the callback function is working for me thanks brother, but why was this happening actually i an new to backend and learning nodejs and mongodb

Comment: That is JavaScript programming. Please feel free to search for _callbacks_ and _async-await_ programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From mongoose [Query guides](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises)

> Don't mix using callbacks and promises with queries, or you may end up
> with duplicate operations. That's because passing a callback to a
> query function immediately executes the query, and calling then()
> executes the query again.

So what you did there was calling `deleteMany` twice, first using the callback and then using the `async/await`. The second attempt will try to delete nothing because the first attempt has already deleted them.

You could try using either one:

```
...
const deleteAllTodos = await TodoModel.deleteMany({ createdBy: id }).exec();
res.send({ 
    success: true, 
    message: "All todos deleted successfully", 
    deleteAllTodos 
})
```

Don't worry about error handling using callback as you have already done it with the `try/catch` block which will catch if any error happened on `deleteMany`.

Comment: Thanks brother removing the callback works for me

Comment: Also thanks for explaining me what I was doing wrong , now i completely understand my mistake thanks again